# Multiple Identical RGBA colours not working

Tags: css, background, rgba

basically I wanted to try have the same rgba value in three different areas. I wanted my body, nav and footer all to have rgba(0,0,0,.8).

My body works but the nav and footer just show was solid black without the transparency...

I've tried changing the transparency slightly so they're different but that doesn't work either.

Are you only allowed to use it once?

Joe

```
@font-face {
        font-family: 'telegraficoregular';
        src: url('../FONTS/telegrafico-webfont.eot');
        src: url('../FONTS/telegrafico-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('../FONTS/telegrafico-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
             url('../FONTS/telegrafico-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('../FONTS/telegrafico-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('../FONTS/telegrafico-webfont.svg#telegraficoregular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;

    }

    .cf:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }

    html, body, head, nav, article, aside, section, h3, h4, footer, ul, li {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    }

    /*Global Styles*/

    html {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    }


    body {

    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    font-family: serif, arial, helvetica, georgia;
    font-size: 16px;


    }

    h1 {

    font-family: telegraficoregular;
    font-size: 3em;
    color: rgb(50,153,187);
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    text-align: center;

    }

    h2 {

    font-family: telegraficoregular;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #003366;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

    }

    p {

    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: black;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:70px;
    }

    h4 + p {

    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: black;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:70px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    }
    /*Nav Styles */

    header {

    background:rgb(233,233,233);
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    margin:0 auto;

    }

    nav {

    background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    width: auto;
    height: 64px;

    }

    nav ul.TopMenu li {

    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 150px;

    }

    nav ul.TopMenu {

    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    }

    nav ul.TopMenu li a {

    display:block;
    line-height: 64px;
    padding:0 2em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: telegraficoregular;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    li {

    position: relative;

    }

    nav ul.SubMenu{

    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -9000em;
    top: 64px;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 0;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:999;
    }

    nav ul.SubMenu li{

    height: 32px;
    font-family: telegraficoregular;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;

    }

    nav ul.SubMenu li a{

    display:block;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    }





    .TopMenu li:hover ul{

    left: 0;
    max-height: 20em;

    }

    ul.SubMenu li a{

    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;


    }

    ul.SubMenu li a:visited {

    color: white;

    }

    ul.SubMenu li a:hover {

    background: rgba(255,165,0,.8);

    }


    a:visited {

    color: white;

    }

    a:hover {

    color: orange; 

    }


    /* Article Styles */

    article {

    width: 896px;
    padding: 32px;

    }


    /*Section Styles */


    section.China {

    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;

    }

    section h3 {

    font-family: telegraficoregular;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    }

    section h4 {

    font-family: telegraficoregular;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-left: 70px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: underline;

    }

    section.China img {

    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }

    section.Australia {

    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;

    }

    section.Australia img {

    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }

    section.Thailand {

    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;

    }

    section.Thailand img {

    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }


    /* Link Styles*/



    /* About Styles */



    #AboutContent{

    width: 960px;
    height: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: white;
    font-family: serif, arial, helvetica, georgia;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;

    }

    #AboutHeader {

    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;

    }

    #AboutHeader img {

    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;

    }

    #AboutHeader h2 {

    font-family: telegraficoregular;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: black;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;

    }

    h2 + img {

    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #AboutHeader p {

    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: black;
    text-align:left;
    padding:50px 0 0 100px;
    }

    /*Photos Content */

    #PhotoContent{

    width: 960px;
    height:auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: white;
    font-family: serif, arial, helvetica, georgia;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;

    }

    /* Photos Gallery */

    #ChinaPhotos {

    width: 960px;
    height:1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: white;
    font-family: serif, arial, helvetica, georgia;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;

    }

    #ChinaPhotos h3 {

    font-family: telegraficoregular;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;

    }

    #ChinaPhotos img {

    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;

    }

    #ChinaPhotos a .Thumb:hover {

    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;

    }

    /* Container Styles */

    #Content {

    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: white;
    font-family: serif, arial, helvetica, georgia;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;

    }


    /* Footer Styles */

    .Footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    }

    .Footer p {

    font-family: telegraficoregular;
    color: white;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;

    }
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your html, but it's possible the elements are overlapping, and thus coming out darker (since it's additive). Two elements with 80% opacity that overlap will look black. 

Try another colour (at full opacity) to debug. You can definitely use rgba on more than one element.

Comment: @Patrick - they're not just added together though. I.e laying a 50% opaque child over a 50% opaque parent doesn't give you a 100% opaque result. However, if you compare to the result of a single 75% opaque element, the result is the same. In the 2 element case, final opacity  is determined by `parentOpacity + child_opacity * (1 - parentOpacity)` - or using the figures above: 0.5 + 0.5*(1-0.5) = 0.5 + 0.5*0.5 = 0.5 + 0.25 = 0.75. If we use 25% for each, a single 43.75% opaque element is same. I.e 0.25 + 0.25 * (1-0.25) = 0.25 + 0.25 * 0.75 = 0.25 + 0.1875 = 0.4375

Comment: @enhzflep Ha ha, yes. I was being simple for clarity of explanation. He wanted to know why this was happening, so I gave the easiest answer to understand, albeit not technically accurate. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Patrick - and thank-you for making me think and investigate further. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks as though it's the overlap that is causing your problems (see comment above. I changed the background colours in the nav and footer and they show up just find.

It's the fact that you have two elements with 80% opacity overlapped, and the outcome looks black.

```css
    html, body, head, nav, article, aside, section, h3, h4, footer, ul, li {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    }

    /*Global Styles*/

    html {

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    }


    body {

    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    font-family: serif, arial, helvetica, georgia;
    font-size: 16px;


    }

    h1 {

    font-family: telegraficoregular;
    font-size: 3em;
    color: rgb(50,153,187);
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    text-align: center;

    }

    h2 {

    font-family: telegraficoregular;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #003366;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;

    }

    p {

    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: black;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:70px;
    }

    h4 + p {

    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: black;
    text-align:left;
    padding-left:70px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    }
    /*Nav Styles */

    header {

    background:rgb(233,233,233);
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    margin:0 auto;

    }

    nav {

    background:rgba(255,0,0,.8);
    width: auto;
    height: 64px;

    }

    nav ul.TopMenu li {

    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 150px;

    }

    nav ul.TopMenu {

    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;

    }

    nav ul.TopMenu li a {

    display:block;
    line-height: 64px;
    padding:0 2em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: telegraficoregular;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    li {

    position: relative;

    }

    nav ul.SubMenu{

    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    left: -9000em;
    top: 64px;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 0;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:999;
    }

    nav ul.SubMenu li{

    height: 32px;
    font-family: telegraficoregular;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;

    }

    nav ul.SubMenu li a{

    display:block;
    line-height: 32px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0;
    }





    .TopMenu li:hover ul{

    left: 0;
    max-height: 20em;

    }

    ul.SubMenu li a{

    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;


    }

    ul.SubMenu li a:visited {

    color: white;

    }

    ul.SubMenu li a:hover {

    background: rgba(255,165,0,.8);

    }


    a:visited {

    color: white;

    }

    a:hover {

    color: orange; 

    }


    /* Article Styles */

    article {

    width: 896px;
    padding: 32px;

    }


    /*Section Styles */


    section.China {

    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;

    }

    section h3 {

    font-family: telegraficoregular;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    }

    section h4 {

    font-family: telegraficoregular;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-left: 70px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: underline;

    }

    section.China img {

    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }

    section.Australia {

    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;

    }

    section.Australia img {

    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }

    section.Thailand {

    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;

    }

    section.Thailand img {

    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }


    /* Link Styles*/



    /* About Styles */



    #AboutContent{

    width: 960px;
    height: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: white;
    font-family: serif, arial, helvetica, georgia;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;

    }

    #AboutHeader {

    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 20px;

    }

    #AboutHeader img {

    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;

    }

    #AboutHeader h2 {

    font-family: telegraficoregular;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: black;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;

    }

    h2 + img {

    position: relative;
    top: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #AboutHeader p {

    font-family: serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: black;
    text-align:left;
    padding:50px 0 0 100px;
    }

    /*Photos Content */

    #PhotoContent{

    width: 960px;
    height:auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: white;
    font-family: serif, arial, helvetica, georgia;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;

    }

    /* Photos Gallery */

    #ChinaPhotos {

    width: 960px;
    height:1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: white;
    font-family: serif, arial, helvetica, georgia;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;

    }

    #ChinaPhotos h3 {

    font-family: telegraficoregular;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;

    }

    #ChinaPhotos img {

    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;

    }

    #ChinaPhotos a .Thumb:hover {

    width: 320px;
    height: 240px;

    }

    /* Container Styles */

    #Content {

    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: white;
    font-family: serif, arial, helvetica, georgia;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;

    }


    /* Footer Styles */

    .Footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background: rgba(0,0,255,.5);
    }

    .Footer p {

    font-family: telegraficoregular;
    color: white;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 80px;
    text-align: center;

    }
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>something</li>
        <li>something else</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<footer class="Footer">
This is a footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Yeah seems to be the case!

I put the nav and footer to transparency '.1' and that seems to be decent enough!

Is there any other solutions to this?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a couple of options, instead of styling body, you could use fixed or absolute positioning of your elements to avoid stacking.